# Как вписать в код метод проверки, того факта, является ли адрес групповым?

Tags: java, сокет, tcp-ip

Фрагмент кода ниже из Шилдта (Java полное руководство, с. 680).

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Objects;

class InetAddressTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(Address);
        Address = InetAddress.getByName("www.lurkmore.to");
        System.out.println(Address);
        InetAddress SW[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("vedomosti.ru");
        for (int i=0; i<SW.length; i ++)
            System.out.println(SW[i]);
    }
}
```

Есть в классе `InetAddress` метод `boolean isMulticastAddress()`. Он возвращает значение `true`, если адрес является групповым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне вписать этот метод в исходный код, чтобы проверить, является ли интернет адрес групповым? 
А то я и так и эдак вписываю, и не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Objects;

public class InetAddressTest {

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    Address = InetAddress.getByName("www.lurkmore.to");
    checkInetAddress(Address);
    InetAddress SW[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("vedomosti.ru");
    for (int i = 0; i < SW.length; i++)
        checkInetAddress(SW[i]);
}

public static void checkInetAddress(InetAddress address){
    if(address.isMulticastAddress()){
        System.out.println("Address :" + address + "is Multicast");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Address :" + address + " not Multicast");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на правду. Спасибо.